# REGEX to match 10 digits and must contain number 4

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I tried to write a regex to match a 10 digits number and it must contain number 4. like:

```
s=['123456abc','abcisjgm','1234567895','1231231231']
for i in s:
    if re.findall(r'[4]\d{9}\b',i):
        print(i, "is valid")
    else:
        print(i, "is not valid")
```

Output as below,

```
123456abc is not valid
abcisjgm is not valid
1234567895 is not valid -----> this should be valid
1231231231 is not valid
```

Comment: Have you had time to review the answers below? If you need more assistance, please let know.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following pattern with `re.search`:

```
^(?=\d*?4)\d{10}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pnRh7w/1).

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=\d*?4)` - there must be `4` after 0 or more digits, as few as possible
- `\d{10}` - ten digits
- `$` - end of string.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/3GiE45):

```
import re

s=['123456abc','abcisjgm','1234567895','1231231231']

for i in s:
    if re.search(r'^(?=\d*?4)\d{10}$', i):
        print(i, "is valid")
    else:
        print(i, "is not valid")
```

Output:

```
123456abc is not valid
abcisjgm is not valid
1234567895 is valid
1231231231 is not valid
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to check for 10 digits using a positive lookahead.

Match digits except 4, then match 4 followed by optional digits.

```
^(?=\d{10}$)[0-35-9]*4\d*$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=\d{10}$)` Assert 10 digits
- `[0-35-9]*` Match 0+ times a digit except 4
- `4` Match the required 4
- `\d*` Match 0+ times a digit
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qYmm8V/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/EXvXBt)

If it can occur multiple times in a string, you might also use word boundaries `\b`

*Example code*

```
import re
s=['123456abc','abcisjgm','1234567895','1231231231']

for i in s:
    if re.findall(r'\b(?=\d{10}$)[0-35-9]*4\d*\b',i):
        print(i, "is valid")
    else:
        print(i, "is not valid")
```

*Output*

```
123456abc is not valid
abcisjgm is not valid
1234567895 is valid
1231231231 is not valid
```